# Multiple number input, jquery .each if val() greater than, add class to element

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, each

I need to loop through a list of input elements of a certain class name. and based on if the value of any of those inputs with the class of "attendeeQuantityInput" is greater than 0, then add a class to an element on a page, if any of those inputs with the class of "attendeeQuantityInput" then remove the class from the element.
I am using jQuery. I tried a .each() but for some reason I am not able to get the value of the input, check it and then add a class to an element.

This is what I have tried so far:

JS

```
$(".AddMinusButton").click(function (event) {
    memberZeroAttendees();
 });

 function memberZeroAttendees() {

    $("#MemberTotalAttendeesPage input[name=memAttendees]").each(function() {
        //alert($(this).val());
        if ($(this).val() == 0 || $(this).val() == null) {
            //alert($(this).attr("class"));

            $('#MemberTotalAttendeesPage .continueBtn').addClass('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#MemberTotalAttendeesPage .continueBtn').removeClass('disabled');
        }


    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="MemberTotalAttendeesPage">
           <div class="attendeesContainer">
               <h3>Member Attendees</h3>
                  <ul class="productVariantList attendeesList">
                   <li>
                    <span class="variantTitle">
                        Member Adult

                    </span>
                    <small>Ages 19-64 </small>
                    <div class="variantQuantity">
                        <span class="minusBtn AddMinusButton">-</span>
                        <input type="number" name="memAttendees" value="" placeholder="0" min="0" max="2" maxlength="2" id="memAdultInput" class="attendeeQuantityInput" />
                        <span class="addBtn AddMinusButton">+</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="variantTitle">
                        Member Junior
                    </span>
                    <small>Ages 11-18 </small>
                    <div class="variantQuantity">
                        <span class="minusBtn AddMinusButton">-</span>
                        <input type="number" name="memAttendees" value="" placeholder="0" min="0" max="2" maxlength="2" class="attendeeQuantityInput" />
                        <span class="addBtn AddMinusButton">+</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="variantTitle">
                        Member Child
                    </span>
                    <small>Ages 3-10 </small>
                    <div class="variantQuantity">
                        <span class="minusBtn AddMinusButton">-</span>
                        <input type="number" name="memAttendees" value="" placeholder="0" min="0" max="2" maxlength="2" class="attendeeQuantityInput" />
                        <span class="addBtn AddMinusButton">+</span>
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <span class="variantTitle">
                        Member Toddler
                    </span>
                    <small>Ages 0-3 </small>
                    <div class="variantQuantity">
                        <span class="minusBtn AddMinusButton">-</span>
                        <input type="number" name="memAttendees" value="" placeholder="0" min="0" maxlength="2" class="attendeeQuantityInput" />
                        <span class="addBtn AddMinusButton">+</span>
                       </div>
                   </li>

            </ul>
           </div>

           <a href="#GATotalAttendeesPage" class="continueBtn">Continue</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: There is no `#MemberTotalAttendeesPage` in your posted HTML markup. If this is a parent element, then post relevant HTML markup, not just part of it

Comment: Do you have an element with the ID `MemberTotalAttendeesPage`? You don't in the example you posted. You're also missing a closing `}` on your function. Seems to work if you fix that http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/xLfLbk72/ (although the logic looks a bit flawed)

Comment: The best investment in yourself as a programmer you can make is to learn debugging - Start by learning how to use either Dev Tools or Firebug. 2 things to start with are 1) console - where you can type things like `$("#MemberTotalAttendeesPage input[name=memAttendees]")` and see if any elements were found. This way you can see whether your selector is correct. Which it is not. Also there you can try any javascript code you are not sure about. 2) Source tab allows you to see your code and place breakpoints . Now you can execute any code line by line and inspect variables in scope and much more

Comment: @A.Wolff and j08691, My apologies, thought that could have been a given.  I added the wrapping element for the relevant markup

Comment: Your question does not make senses. It also doesn't coincide with your JavaScript sample (in question you use generic class "myClass" and in the sample it's all specific classes). Please edit your question to be more specific.

Comment: @Yann, Edited the question to reflect the correct class name.

Comment: Which line of your code does not behave like you expect it to? maybe this would work: `$('#MemberTotalAttendeesPage input[name="memAttendees"]')`?

Comment: @Konstantin, first, thank you for asking a relevant question to help me rather than tearing a part my question. The part that does not work correctly seems to be the .each() loop.  The class (disabled) only gets added to my element (continueBtn) when the last input box is greater than 1. Not any of the other ones.

Comment: Since there is no element with id = MemberTotalAttendeesPage it's difficult to understand what you are doing wrong?

Comment: @ClosDesign `I added the wrapping element for the relevant markup` No you didn't as i can see it

Comment: how about using `$('.attendeesContainer input[name="memAttendees"]')`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about the line with `....each()` - use console to see whether your can select anything with your selector.

But there is another line that will give you trouble

```
 $(this).val() == 0 || $(this).val() == null
```

What about `$(this).val() == ''` and `$(this).val() == undefined`?

you might consider using

```
 if (parseInt($(this).val()) && parseInt($(this).val()) > 0 ) { ... } else {...}
```

Also the logic is kind of weird, because you continue to iterate over your inputs even after you found one that should enable or disable.

i'd start by disabling the button and then iterate over `each` and if one is found with value > 0 then 'enable'

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite know why this works but this is the answer I found for myself.
This is only the Function that I needed for my loop.  I am only posting the function because this is what was needed.

Hopefully it helps someone else.

```
 function memberZeroAttendees() {

    var validate= false;
    $('#MemberTotalAttendeesPage input').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() >= 1)
            validate = true;
    });
    if(!validate){
        $('#MemberTotalAttendeesPage .continueBtn').addClass('disabled');
        //return false;
    }
    else { 
        $('#MemberTotalAttendeesPage .continueBtn').removeClass('disabled');
    }
}
```